# SQL Create a unique number or value from multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the unique unit measure of a dataset, is there an easy way to create a unique value for a collection of columns( what I think should be the unit)

E.g.

```
Select 
(TRANACTION||CODE||ID||DATE)
FROM X
```

Id ideally like to turn this into single value or find the lowest combination granularity possible.

or can i just use that and row_number over it?

Comment: You'll have to do some exploration to find what set of columns represents the unique key of the data. You can use the [`QUALIFY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/HIRUG/ch12s04s04s09.html) clause (if your version supports it). `SELECT * FROM yourtable QUALIFY COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY TRANSACTION, CODE, ID, DATE, etc) > 1;` If you find the a combination then that will return no records. If you get 2 or more records back, then you can see within those records where the duplicate lies and take another stab at it.

Comment: ORA_HASH can take a list of concatenated list of columns and output a for all intents and purposes unique value. If your goal is to get 1 record per list of columns, yeah, you can do row_number() partitioning by that list and filter on 1.

Comment: "..find the lowest combination granularity possible..." -- I think this could be a futile exercise. Maybe the rules for the lowest combination could be valid for one data set, but won't be for the next one and, thus, could be a risky approach. I would play it safe and use `ROW_NUMBER()` and I would sleep well at night.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd ideally like to turn this into single value or find the lowest combination granularity possible.

If you want to find a unique value for each distinct combination of  `TRANACTION`, `CODE`, `ID`, `DATE` then use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tranaction, code, id, "DATE") AS value
FROM   x
```

After an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` then the numeric value assigned to each row is likely to change but you would assign each unique combination an atomically increasing value each time.

If you don't want to number rows with identical tuples of values with the same number then use `ROW_NUMBER` rather than `DENSE_RANK`.